# std::shared_ptr takes lot more memory space than vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a voxel structure as:

```
struct voxel
{
    unsigned char R, G, B;
    voxel()
    {
        R = G = B = 0;
    }
    //parameteric contructor with parameters
    voxel(unsigned char pR, unsigned char pG, unsigned char pB)
    {
        R = pR; G = pG; B = pB;
    }
};
```

I have a very large n for number of voxels.

```
int n = 300 * 300 * 300;
```

Now when i initialize voxels with vector it takes approximately 79 MB in RAM.

```
std::vector< voxel > vi(n);
```

But it takes more than 2 GB when i initialize it this way using shared_ptr and stack overflows.

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<voxel> > vi(n);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    vi.push_back(std::shared_ptr<voxel>(new voxel()));
}
```

What could be the reason for this behavior and how can i avoid it?

Additional Notes:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<voxel> > vi(n); //statement takes 211 MB alone
```

Update:
I have also tried with this loop instead of push back but the result is same. I now have a general gist of why is this happening.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vi[i].reset(new voxel());
        vi[i]->B = 0;
        vi[i]->R = 0;
        vi[i]->G = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that when you set the size of a vector (using e.g. the constructor like you do), and then call `push_back` you increase the size of the vector. So in your example you are creating a vector with `2*n` elements. Then you got to remember the overhead of storing the pointer itself, and on a 64-bit system the pointer is 8 bytes compared to your structure of 3 bytes.

Comment: It stack overflows? Are you sure?

Comment: it gives error of std::bad_alloc at memory location. This is generally because of overflow, right?

Comment: Heap exhaustion, rather than stack overflow.  And quite likely due to fragmentation rather than 'real' exhaustion, since the vector will be reallocated multiple times, with numerous heap allocations for the voxels _and_ shared pointer control blocks between each reallocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::vector< voxel > vi(n);
```

Is going to take up `sizeof(voxel) * n` bytes of memory.  When you change to a shared pointer you are now going to have the cost of the shared pointer and the  the `voxel`. That would be equivilent to

```
sizeof(voxel) * n + sizeof(std::shared_ptr<voxel>) * n
```

Where the `sizeof(std::shared_ptr<voxel>)` is likely to be 16 bytes.

You are also wasting a lot of space in your second example as you declare

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<voxel> > vi(n);
```

Which is going to create `n` empty `shared_ptr`s and then you `push_back` another `n` non empty `shared_ptr`s so you doulbe the size of the vector.  If you want to preallocate the size of the `vector` then you should use

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<voxel> > vi;
vi.reserve(n);
```

Comment: @Jeremy Correct.  Edited answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, a `voxel` and a `shared_ptr<voxel>` are not the same thing, so I don't quite understand why you think they should have the same size. A `shared_ptr<voxel>` represents, at minimum, the size of a `voxel` *plus* a pointer and some reference counting information. That's all got to be stored somewhere.

Your second example is also flawed in that it has twice as many elements as in the first example: you initialise with `n` "null pointer" elements then `push_back` `n` more.

Comment: not the DV but I think your size is incorrect.  a `shared_ptr` is probably 2 pointers plus you have the size of the things they are pointing to.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The precise contents are (a) unspecified, (b) irrelevant. The key point is "of course it's bigger". However you are right in that I missed out an "at least" that I'd intended.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As an aside, out of interest, why two? One for the pointee and another for the original `shared_ptr`? If so, I counted the latter as my "some reference counting information", FWIW.

Comment: AFAKI most `shared_ptr` have a pointer the the use counter and a pointer to the object of the type they are for.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Alright, then my original version was accurate ;)